# openssh-server package not available on 12.04.2

Tags: 12.04, software-installation, openssh

I have just done a fresh install of 12.04.2 and found out that i could not ssh to this PC.
I tried to install openssh-server but it said that "Package openssh-server is not available..."
What is missing?

Comment: Actually **openssh-server** is in the **main** repository for *Ubuntu 12.04*. Did you definitely try: **`sudo apt-get install openssh-server`** (all lower-case)? See: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/base/openssh-server

Comment: Please accept an answer so that people can see that the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 7):

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

If that doesn't work, open the Ubuntu Software Center and browse to *Edit* -> *Software Sources* -> *Ubuntu Software* tab, and make sure that you have at least the main, universe and multiverse repositories marked with a check mark.

Comment: Yes I did that "sudo apt-get install openssh-server" before and it was saying the same. The problem was I was just doing a apt-get upgrade and not a update. After I did a update and ran the same command it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Ubuntu Software Centre and browse to the *Edit* -> *Software Sources* -> *Ubuntu Software* tab. Then select *Other* -> *Select Best Server* under *Download From*.

Afterwards run in a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openssh-server`

Follow the on-screen instructions. This will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was following the advice to remove and re-install openssh-server via CLI, but got an error saying the package was not available.

Update `apt-get` then tried again with success.

So, the sequence that succeeded was:

```
sudo apt-get remove openssh-client openssh-server
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

Comment: lol wtf removal of ssh client will break almost every packet in your system

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because in installed Ubuntu on a virtual machine, but i didn't connect it to internet because i used a private switch. I just changed the switch and connect it to internet with a private switch. After that i changed the sources code and chose one for my case (Germany). Now it working.
You can try the same and i hope everything gonna for you too. (Don't forget to run the update)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If all else fails you can find the package available for your distribution via the under-utilized [Ubuntu Package Search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/)

In your case it will be found [here.](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openssh-server&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all)